# How to axiomatize oddness

Tags: logic, model-theory

I'm trying to axiomatize the following statement in first order language: "every polynomial of an odd degree has a root" using infix notation.

For example, I can write "every polynomial of degree n has a root" as follows:

$\forall a_1\forall a_2...\forall a_n(a_n\neq 0 \rightarrow \exists x(a_1x^1+a_2x^2+...+a_nx^n=0))$

But how can I make $n$ to be odd? i.e. $\exists m\in\mathbb{N} (n=2m+1)$. Obviously we can't specify the variable $m$ to be a natural number.

Comment: If you write $\exists x\forall a_1\forall a_2...\forall a_n$ then you say that there is an $x$ such that all degree-$n$ polynomials has a root at $x$ (i.e. the same $x$ works for all polynomials). I think you want to do it the other way: $\forall a_1\forall a_2...\forall a_n\exists x$ says that any polynomial has some root.

Comment: The idea is that if I denote the sentence as $\phi(n)$, then the set of axioms would be $\{\phi(1), \phi(3), \phi(5),...\}$. There will be infinitely (and countably) many of them. So there has got to be a way to recursively define the sentences.

Comment: When you say "in first order language", it is common to specify *which* language.

Comment: It's the language of an ordered field.

Comment: That's what I figured from the context. And you should have explicitly said that in your post.

Comment: reminder that the theory of algebraically closed fields is not finitely axiomatisable

Answer (score 4):

This is not a single statement. It is a *schema*. For every odd integers $n$, we write the following sentence:
$$\forall a_0\ldots\forall a_n\exists x(a_n\neq 0\rightarrow a_n x^n+\ldots+a_0=0),$$
Presumably, we are in the language of rings, so the exponentiation is just a shorthand for repeated multiplication.

But the oddity of $n$ is in the meta-theory. Not in the theory.

Comment: Could you quantize like $\forall a\in \Bbb R^{2n+1}$ instead and make it a single statement?

Comment: I don't see how. You also want this for every $n$, which why this is a schema. The statement I wrote is effectively quantifying over $\Bbb R^n$ for an odd $n$.

Comment: When I construct the set of axioms $\Sigma$, can I write $\Sigma=\{\phi(n): \exists m\in\mathbb{N}(n=2m+1)\}$? Assuming $\phi(n)$ denotes the sentence with $a_n\neq 0$?

Comment: Could one possibly describe the function $\bigcup\{\Bbb R^{m+1}\times \Bbb R\mid m\in \Bbb N\}\to \Bbb R$ that takes $((a_0,\ldots,a_m), x)$ and evaluates the polynomial $a_0 + a_1x + \cdots a_mx^m$? I mean, at first glance it seems like a reasonable function to me. I just don't know whether it exists. Maybe replacement?

Comment: @Sid: You can write *anything*, as long as you explain exactly what you mean. Yes, you could say that $\phi(n)$, or $\phi_n$ (not to hint that $n$ is a free variable) is the sentence such and such, and then take $\{\phi_n\mid n\text{ is odd}\}$.

Comment: @Arthur: Yes. But now how can you get that for ***every*** $n$, when you cannot quantify over $n$?

Comment: @AsafKaragila Even if $\mathbb{N}$ is not in the language?

Comment: @Sid: The set $\{\varphi_n\mid \ldots\}$ is not "in the language" to begin with. This is why you should probably use subscript as an index and not $\phi(n)$ which might hint this is a variable variable.